# How to upload image on server from iphone application?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [upload image from iphone to the server folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939335/upload-image-from-iphone-to-the-server-folder)

How to upload image,video,audio or any text format file on server from iphone application?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to do an HTTP POST in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format or `multipart/form-data` format.  You should have a look at the [ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

In particular, [this section](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest) will help with POST uploads.