# iOS: get images from gallery

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gallery

Is there a way to get all gallery photos paths in iOS?
I dont need to pick and display it, i need only the paths.

Answer (score 3):

Check the recently SO post for getting image URL through `ALAssest`  ..

[Upload ALAsset URL images to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442653/upload-alasset-url-images-to-the-server/5442787#5442787)

There is another post,

[display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone)