# How can I upload multiple images?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I would like to upload images along with a couple fields of data to a server from my app. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Have you started using anything such as NSURLConnection or ASIHttpRequest?

Comment: Please find the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442653/upload-alasset-url-images-to-the-server

Comment: I was going to use a POST request with NSURLConnection, but I didn't know how to make a data object out of multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

many web services do that like JSON Soap rest, you should learn to program a web service along with programming iOS.