# Uploading image in png format with iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, post, httpwebrequest

I want to upload an image in png format to a server.I have to give three parameters with the request which are

- `transactionID: (any random integer)`
- `signatureBytes:data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAsdffsdfsdfsdfsdfYAAAAeGRPoAAAgAElEQVR4nO2de5BmRXnGHzWmYkKVKUqJRk0erwerrwds55/lVnT/mm+87/Z4+3f30+/YN6D9L48CMA9VxnOJ9S`
- `guid: CAD1CBE7-B5A4-43d6-BCDD-89B16F97E3C4`

I have used the code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image,90);

// setting up the URL to post to


NSString *urlString=@"http://www.riverport.net/icalibur/dev/signature.ashx";

// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"transactionID\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[[NSString stringWithString:@"7" intva] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"signatureBytes\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"data:image/png;base64,iVBUaBCrFDXGSIECEXEFdUFEhEVAluXmsrrtrrttrrqddcsvrgergergg/YN6D9L4uozc5h+nsWsFhGSn88CWAAwqV2ynoz1qvJjYTmfCOk1QxJ0ANgHijoZDy8CMA9VxnOJ9S"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"guid\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"CHJ78G-B5A4-43d6-BCDD-CFG567FGJ"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];


NSString* returns= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:body encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



//NSLog(@"body %@",stri);


// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(returnString);
```

and the response from server is:

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) +201
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value) +66

[InvalidCastException: Conversion from string &quot;����
```

Have anybody any idea What could be the problem.I do not know if i am doing it right .

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801049/uploading-photo-through-programing-in-objective-c/5801303#5801303 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939335/upload-image-from-iphone-to-the-server-folder

Answer (score 3):

From the errors you received i believe that you don't set your parameters correctly for the request.

Why don't you use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) to upload your photo? it has a class ASIFormDataRequest that you can use to make POST or GET requests and you can add parameters to it really easy.

[here](http://dougdiego.com/2009/04/08/asihttprequest-uploading-photos/) is an example of uploading images with ASIHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 2):

You're not formatting the upload data correctly. The post data should look something like this:

```
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"

value-for-foo
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bar"

value-for-bar
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="filename.ext"
Content-Type: application/whatever

file data
--boundary--
```

Note how there is a blank line ("\r\n\r\n") in between the headers and the value of the field, a crlf after the value, and a repeat of the boundary before the next field's header. You have none of that in your code, your output looks more like this:

```
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"
value-for-fooContent-Disposition: form-data; name="bar"
value-for-barContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="filename.ext"
Content-Type: application/whatever

file data--boundary--
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Pankaj
I am not sure but just try only image NSData with out transactionID and guide parameter,
your code seems ok.
Please let me know result.

Comment: No the server only responds to request with all parameters

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to post a PNG-image but you are fetching the JPEG-representation in your code-snippet. Is it solved by changing to **UIImagePNGRepresentation**?