# Auto upload camera roll in iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera

I am struggling to find something useful for automatically uploading photos from photo library to my server end.
In my iphone application i wan to automatically upload the photos to server as user captures a new photo.
The way facebook, Dropbox and google plus app doing.

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly It's a **3 Step Process :**

**1)** Get the photo. Store it to the **Documents Directory**. Apple has described it very well here : [PhotoPicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196)

**2)** Fetch the Photo from **Document Directory** :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Images"];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourImage.png"]]];
```

**3)** Now , you can upload your Photo to the Server. The Process is well described Here :
[upload image from iphone to the server folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939335/upload-image-from-iphone-to-the-server-folder)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My question is how i can track which photos are already uploaded to server and which are new one which i need to upload. Also as per comment somewhere , They say we need to execute this process in background to keep streaming the photos to server. So when app will go in background what will happen?

Comment: Is there a way to upload without copying the asset to the `Documents` directory ? I know NSURLSession will put the upload in the background, but can you upload an asset without creating a local copy?

Comment: @AlexSpencer:  
    ALAssetRepresentation *represent = asset.defaultRepresentation;
    unsigned long representSize=(unsigned long)represent.size;
    Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(representSize);
    NSUInteger buffered = [represent getBytes:buffer
                                   fromOffset:0.0
                                       length:representSize
                                        error:nil];    // you should check for errors tho!
    // Get the data
    NSData *dataUpload = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];

Comment: alasset covert to NSData (like above comment )otherwise u will not get the Exif info like location.