# Implementing iOS camera upload

Tags: ios, background, camera, image-uploading

Dropbox, Google Photo and other apps support something called "Camera Uploads" option. This uploads all new photos were taken by the device automatically w/o need to launch the application.

How to implement similar functionality? What APIs to use? Are there dev guides describing the solution or part of it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Wrong place to ask for this.

Comment: Why is that do you think? It is not a "recommend me the best" question. It is a "how to do it" question.

Comment: I think because it is asking for a "how do I do xyz" and not a specific problem, what you have tried etc. However, You can check for many duplicates similiar to this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682782/auto-upload-camera-roll-in-iphone-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741251/ios-background-uploading-of-photos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405903/how-we-can-upload-camera-roll-image-automatically-to-server https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ios+upload+camera+roll+background+stackoverflow&*

Comment: Check this too: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/500

Comment: Those are 4, 4 and two years old questions. SDKs have changed since then. And the answers weren't mutch help either.

Comment: You asked how to implement simliar functionality. Even the **Dropbox** website link tells you that it is a background task in iOS. It's not a "Camera upload options" that is integrated in iOS or some framework. It is custom implemented background tasks that connects to their custom API with custom Code. I'm not really sure what more you want to know? Read the dropbox link "Dropbox app stops uploading shortly after you close it and resumes uploading only when you open it again. This is due to a time limit iOS puts on **apps running in the background.**".

Comment: That can be an answer actually

Comment: Glad to help, it's np I think it falls in same as the previous linked questions so If you got the answer you can delete the question if you want. Or you can change the question title to specifically ask for dropbox/google if someone searches for the same question,  as mention in your info and I can add the answer.